# Remove from a list where a elements value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, lambda

I am trying to remove from a list in a list where there are null.

For Example:

```
responses.Questions[0].Options[0].Value = "asdf";
responses.Questions[0].Options[1].Value = null;
responses.Questions[0].Options[2].Value = 1;
```

I want to remove the second options in the list because the value is null. So When I am done I have a list like so:

```
responses.Questions[0].Options[0].Value = "asdf";
responses.Questions[0].Options[1].Value = 1;
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't appear to work:

```
responses.Questions.Select(q => q.Options.RemoveAll(o => o.Value == null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Where` clause in order to exclude `null` option lists:

```
responses.Questions
    .Where(q => q.Options != null)
    .ForEach(q => q.Options.RemoveAll(o => o.Value == null));
```

(According to one of your comments that is deleted now, you got an exception because of `Options` being `null`.)

Note: `null` values can appear at different levels here. `responses`, `Questions`, `q` and `Options` could theoretically all be `null`. Add tests where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks I quickly figured it out after I had hit add comment. I did exactly this though

Answer (score 3):

use `foreach`:

```
foreach(var q in responses.Questions)
{
    q.Options.RemoveAll(o => o.Value == null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
responses.Questions.ForEach(q => q.Options.RemoveAll(o => o.Value == null));
```

Comment: awesome I am choosing this one because its a one liner.

Comment: I still wonder why the `Select` variant didn't work. While it was a missuse of `Select`, it should still have worked.